# Select which part of file to download

Tags: python, bittorrent, libtorrent

I'm trying to develop my own torrent app using **Python**. After some research I decided to go with **libtorrent**, and found this interesting answer:

- [How to write a simple Bittorrent application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400828/how-to-write-a-simple-bittorrent-application/5494823#5494823)

I've found also another similar question with one answer:

- [Priorize torrent download sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339532/prioritizing-torrent-download-sequences-using-libtorrent)

but there I couldn't understand how to do it, I read the full documentation they link in the question and didn't get any idea about how to face this.

I've been looking around libtorrent trying to understand how could I manage the download...

- How could I to start downloading from the beginning to the end ?

My goal is to start the download the torrent "*ordered*", meaning I don't want to download random parts of the torrent, the ones availables at the moment, I would like to download it from the beginning to the end.

If anybody has try this and could point me to the right **libtorrent** documentation would be awesome !!!

---

- How could I start to download the file ordered ? -->  `set_sequential_download()`

But how could I wait for the pieces ? How do I configure libtorrent to wait for the first 10 pieces until begin with the next 10 ?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to download pieces in order is to call [set_sequential_download()](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#set_sequential_download()) on the torrent_handle for that torrent. That's piece order, starting with piece 0, 1, 2 etc. The order files are downloaded depend on the order they are specified in the .torrent file (i.e. often a seemingly arbitrary order).

Note that this will make libtorrent *request* pieces in order, they won't necessarily *complete* in-order. If what you really want is to *stream* files, i.e. play back as you're downloading, you want to aim for *completing* pieces in order, which has a subtle difference. For streaming, you want to look at [set_piece_deadline()](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#set_piece_deadline()), which will request such pieces using a different [piece-picking mechanism](http://libtorrent.org/streaming.html).

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer ! I read about sequential download, but as you've said that not force the pieces to download in order. How would you use `set_piece_deadline()` to ensure the file is download ordered ?

Comment: set increasing deadlines for the pieces you want to be downloaded later. for instance, you could increment the timeout by 1 ms per piece.